# Permission denied on mounted nfs folders

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs, kerberos

I'm trying to mount home directories over nfs on a few clients. Mounting works but I cannot `cd /srv/nfs4`: `Permission denied`. `root` can enter those mounted directories and read files there. Checking as root, files show up with the correct user names, groups, uids and gids.

Checking as a regular user:

```
testuser@nastest:/srv$ ls -l
ls: cannot access 'nfs4': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? nfs4
testuser@nastest:/srv$ cd nfs4
-bash: cd: nfs4: Permission denied
```

#### My setup

Two fresh vms (kms on proxmox) with Ubuntu 16.04: `nas.domain.tld` and `nastest.domain.tld`, enrolled to a *FreeIPA* domain on `auth.domain.tld`, so user names and uids are centrally managed.

My `/etc/exports`:

```
srv/nfs4               gss/krb5i(rw,fsid=root,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
/srv/nfs4/homes         gss/krb5i(rw,no_subtree_check)
```

`/srv/nfs4`is just a directory (`root`:`root`, `755`), `/srv/nfs4/homes` is bind-mounted to `/home` where a directory owned by a *FreeIPA*-based user exists (`755`).

On the client, `/etc/fstab`:

```
nas.domain.tld:/ /srv/nfs4/ nfs4 sec=krb5i 0 0
```

RDNS works, I've explicitly set the same domain for both hosts in `/etc/idmapd.conf`.

How can I make this work for regular users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I have filed a bug against the freeipa-client package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freeipa/+bug/1733571).

The problem was that `gssd` in Ubuntu 16.04 does not seem to support kernel keyring backed credential caches for kerberos. However, the `ipa-client-install` script creates `/etc/krb5.conf` in a way that relies on those.

Deleting the line `default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}` fixed the issue for me.